# Anemometer - query on analysing the slow logs

Tags: mysql, tools, performance, anemometer, slow-log

I'm new to SQL anemometer. I need to know whether this tool would be able to query to the source database and analyze the slow query logs on real time or not?

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/box/Anemometer/wiki):

> Anemometer is a tool for visualizing collected data from the MySQL Slow Query Log. The name comes from the instrument in a weather station that measures wind speed. SQL queries are like the wind -- ephemeral and hard to get a hold of. Anemometer helps you get a handle on your queries; it makes it easier to figure out what to optimize and how to track performance over time.
>
> Anemometer relies on the Percona Toolkit to do the slow query log collection. Specifically you can run `pt-query-digest`. To parse your slow logs and insert them into a database for reporting.

From the documentation of [pt-query-digest](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-query-digest.html)

> Usage
>
> `pt-query-digest [OPTIONS] [FILES] [DSN]`
>
> pt-query-digest analyzes MySQL queries from slow, general, and binary log files. It can also analyze queries from SHOW PROCESSLIST and MySQL protocol data from tcpdump. By default, queries are grouped by fingerprint and reported in descending order of query time (i.e. the slowest queries first). If no FILES are given, the tool reads STDIN. The optional DSN is used for certain options like --since and --until.
>
> [...]
>
> Capture MySQL protocol data with tcppdump, then report the slowest queries:
>
> `tcpdump -s 65535 -x -nn -q -tttt -i any -c 1000 port 3306 > mysql.tcp.txt`
>
> `pt-query-digest --type tcpdump mysql.tcp.txt`

`tcpdump` monitors real-time data... that is, *in principle*, the answer is **yes**, although **not** by looking at the slow log. However the actual setup doesn't look easy, and requires running from the server machine (as `tcpdump` works locally), not by *remotely* querying the database.